# Deadlock on ReentrantLock in interceptor

Tags: android, kotlin, deadlock, interceptor, reentrantlock

I have next problem. When my token is expired I try to refresh it. If this refresh code called by single-thread it works fine, but if there are two or more threads sometimes I catch deadlock.

This is my code in `Interceptor`:

```
private val lock = ReentrantLock()
...
private fun tryRefreshToken(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Boolean {

        if (lock.tryLock()) { // refresh token by single thread
            try {
                tryRefreshToken(chain, credentialsProvider)
            } catch (e: TokenRefreshFailedException) {
                return false
            } finally {
                lock.unlock()
                }
            return true
        } else {
            // another threads should wait here for token refresh
            lock.lock() // here I catch deadlock
            return true
        }
    }
```

If this method return `true` - the token is refreshed, `false` - if token refreshing is failed.

How to fix my deadlock and where is my error?

Comment: You can use the `synchronized` method or block

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha show your variant?

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31656463/3946958

Comment: why are you not using `lock.lock()` in first place?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha please read my post again!

Comment: @RahulKumar because I want refresh token only by first thread and other threads should wait for it

Comment: what about specifying locking at the place where you are checking if token needs to be refreshed? That way, if you want to refresh token, token will be refreshed and all the waiting threads will get cached token after its been refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement, you have to create Producer-Consumer of token...
You have to use lock/wait and notify, so the first thread will be updating the token and other thread will wait until the updating thread notify them...
sample application on this [oracle link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

Answer (score 0):

I debug and read logs and I find resolve for my problem:

```
else {
        // another threads should wait here for token refresh
        lock.lock() // here I wait for token refresh
        lock.unlock() // here I free monitor
        return true
    }
```