# Does synchronized work for all methods in a class or only 1?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

e.g. thread 1 from class 1 accesses synchronized method 1 of sub class A. Then thread 2 from class 2 accessed synchronized method 1 from same sub class A. Everything is fine here.

If I have thread 3 from class 3 access the synchronized method 2 of sub class A, will it still forbid thread 1 and thread 2 from accessing method 1 while method 2 is doing its thing? If not, how can I achieve that?

Comment: doc: "For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class object for the method's class is used. 

For an instance method, the monitor associated with this (the object for which the method was invoked) is used." if monitor is same, one thread must wait

Comment: yes it the short answer. Put a sleep in method 2 and check to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JLS, § 17.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1) is quite verbose about this:

> A synchronized method ([§8.4.3.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6)) automatically performs a lock action when it is invoked; its body is not executed until the lock action has successfully completed. If the method is an instance method, it locks the monitor associated with the instance for which it was invoked (that is, the object that will be known as `this` during execution of the body of the method). If the method is static, it locks the monitor associated with the Class object that represents the class in which the method is defined. If execution of the method's body is ever completed, either normally or abruptly, an unlock action is automatically performed on that same monitor.

[Oracle's official tutorial on synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) phrases it a little bit more understandable:

> ...
>
> - First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. ...
>
> ...

Answer (score 1):

A `synchronized` method is just a shortcut way to write a method whose body is a `synchronized` block. This;

```
synchronized AnyType foobar(...) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Is just a shortcut way of writing this;

```
AnyType foobar(...) {
    synchronized(this) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

More detail can be found in [Java synchronized method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31656463/801894)

---

**P.S.,**

> If I have thread 3 from class 3...

Threads aren't "from classes." Threads are just objects that execute your code. When your program creates a new thread, the system doesn't remember or care what method of what class created it, and the system doesn't even remember or care what other thread created it.

Answer (score 0):

You ask (assuming instance methods and not static methods):

```
Thread 1 ---executes--> classA.method1
Thread 2 ---executes--> classA.method1
```

then

```
Thread 3 ---executes--> classA.method2
```

Both method1 and method2 are synchronized instance methods in the same class.

*Result*:
Both `method1` and `method2` have the same **monitor** (the `this` instance) and one thread at a time will get the lock and execute `method1` or `method2` and no other thread will be able to unless the thread executing the methods exits and the monitor becomes available to be locked.

The key to understanding is that the **monitor** is the **same** for all the two methods.

Comment: Let's say that only method1 is synchronized, and method2 is not. How does it behave then?
If thread 1 is executing method1, no other threads can execute the method2, because the monitor (classA) is blocked? 

And if thread 1 is executing method2, other thread can execute method1 because method2 is not synchronized? Or the thread2 cannot execute the method1 till method2 finishes, because classA cannot be blocked till it is used by an another thread (thread1)?

Comment: If method2 is not synchronized then any number of threads can access it concurrently. The monitor for a synchronized instance method is the instance ("this") and not the class as you say.